# JS: Trying to use setTimeout with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, settimeout

I need to make modal window to appear after 1 second when page loaded, something wrong with js code, cant figure out what i've been doing wrong.

Here is my code:

Open Window

### Form

Email:

Close

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $("#modal").show();
        }, 1000);
    })  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct, `show` is a jQuery method used for something different. Try with this

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
```